# Regarding permissions on intermediate folders created using "mkdir -pm 764 a/b/c"

Tags: permissions, mkdir

When I am using `mkdir -pm 764 a/b/c`
then only `c` got that 764 permission, while `a` and `b` have default permission. Why does it so? Why doesn't all directories get 764 permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mkdir` utility creates a single directory.  When used with `-m` it creates the directory and effectively runs `chmod` on it with the given permissions (although this does not happen in two steps, which could be important under some circumstances).

With `-p`, any intermediate directories that does not already exist are created.  The mode given to `-m` still only applies to the last name in the pathname, since that is the directory that you're wanting to create (the intermediate directories are created to allow the creation of that directory with the given mode).

The [POSIX standard for `mkdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/mkdir.html) say that each intermediate directory should be created with the mode `(S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR|~filemask)&0777` where `filemask` is your shell's umask value.

In the "Application Usage" section, it says

> [...] For intermediate pathname components created by `mkdir`, the mode is the default modified by `u+ wx` so that the subdirectories can always be created regardless of the file mode creation mask; if different ultimate permissions are desired for the intermediate directories, they can be changed afterwards with `chmod`.

This means that the mode for the intermediate directories is set to allow you to create a directory that potentially have no user write or execute permissions.  If the intermediate directories also were given no execute and/or write permissions, the last components of the directory path would not be able to be created.

In your specific case, use

```
mkdir -p -m 764 a/b/c
chmod 764 a/b
chmod 764 a
```

If you know for sure that none of the directories previously existed, use

```
mkdir -p -m 764 a/b/c
chmod -R 764 a
```